# Zeta Function Result I

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

> $f_k(n)$ denote the number of representation of $n$ as a product of $k$ factors greater than unity. Let $f(1)= 1$, $f(n)$ be the number of representaitons of $n$ as a product of factors greater than unity. (Order is essential).
>
> We have $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{f_k(n)}{n^s} = (\zeta(s)-1)^k$ for $\sigma > 1$. Hence,
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^s} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\zeta(s)-1)^k = 1 + \frac{ \zeta(s)-1}{ 1 - (\zeta(s)-1)} =\frac{1}{2 - \zeta(s) }$$
> $\zeta(s)=2$ for $s= \alpha$, $\alpha > 1$. So $|\zeta(s)| < 2 $ for $\sigma > \alpha$, *so that equation holds for* $\sigma > \alpha$. (p7, Titchmarsh)

What I don't understand is we require $|\zeta(s)-1| < 1$ for geometric series to be written in closed form - and we are given $|\zeta(s)|<2$. So why does the itacilized line hold?

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ converges iff $|r|<1$.

Comment: Yes, so why does $|\zeta(s)|< 2 \Rightarrow |\zeta(s)-1| < 1$?

Comment: It doesn't: what is true is that for $\Re(s)\ge\alpha$, $|\zeta(s)-1|\le\zeta(\alpha)-1$ etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense now.

Comment: Did you prove that Dirichlet series always have an [abscissa of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence) ? Here we prove the equality for $\Re(s)$ large enough, then we search for the abscissa of convergence of the LHS